# price difference table in sql with date

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have following table in my database.

```
ID  DATE            HOTEL_NAME   PRICE
1   16-01-2012      AA           32.00
2   16-01-2012      BC           45.00
3   16-01-2012      DE           47.00
4   17-01-2012      AA           33.20
5   17-01-2012      BC           43.00
6   17-01-2012      DE           51.40
```

I want result like this :

```
ID  DATE_1       DATE_2       HOTEL_NAME  PRICE_1   PRICE_2   DIFFERENCE
1   16-01-2012   17-01-2012   AA          32.00     33.20     1.20
2   16-01-2012   17-01-2012   BC          45.00     43.00     -2.00
3   16-01-2012   17-01-2012   DE          47.00     51.40     4.40
```

Please tell me the sql query to optimize this result.

Thanks

Comment: Optimize what? You already have some code that needs optimization? Could you show it please? Because without seeing your current attempt it would be a little difficult to optimize it. Because you know, when you try to optimize zero you get zero. The whole point of my gibberish comment is to ask you [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: IT also depends on the RDBMS that you are using.  MySQL, SQL Server, Oracly, SQLite, etc, all have different capabilities.

Comment: A little harsh, Darin! The guy's obviously just misunderstood what the word "optimize" means. Replace that with "generate" and it makes some sense (although he/she could do with specifying if this is the difference between two specific dates, or between all availble dates, or quite what).

Comment: @AlastairMaw, I understand that. Except that I am not replacing the word *"optimize"* with *"generate"*. I am replacing it with *"gimme teh dodez"* which is not how StackOverflow is meant to be used.

Comment: Do you really only have two dates in the table?  What do you want when there are more dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify an RDBMS that you are using. But this solution should work for all of them:

```
select t1.id, t1.dt date_1, t2.dt date_2, t1.hotel,
    t1.price price_1, t2.price price_2, t1.price - t2.price difference
from test t1
inner join
(
    select id, dt, hotel, price
    from test
) t2
    on t1.hotel = t2.hotel
    and t1.dt < t2.dt
```

See [SQL Fiddle with a Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f29d0/1)

Comment: Oops.. I forgot my "on" clause - this is what I meant. Good job! +1

Comment: Thanku very much bluefeet. For your answer with demo. I am surprised to see this response within few hour of my post. I really thanks to you from deep of my heart..And i was using SQL Express with Visual studio.(-:Vicky.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do what you want I believe:

```
SELECT a.id, a.date, b.date, a.hotel_name, a.price, b.price, (a.price - b.price) FROM  table AS a, table AS b WHERE a.hotel_name = b.hotel_name;
```